# what is the maxium version of standalone asio can I use in VS2010?

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I want to use asio but don't want to use boost in vs2010,so what is the maxium version of asio standalone version can I use in vs2010?
I saw this in [asio-1.12.2](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.12.2/doc/asio/using.html)

> Win64 using Visual C++ 9.0 or later

so I think asio-1.12.2 can use in vs2010 standalone,and don't to download boost.but when I include "asio.hpp" in my project and defined "ASIO_STANDALONE",vs2010 gave me some error.

```
#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    asio::io_context io;

    asio::steady_timer t(io, asio::chrono::seconds(5));
    t.wait();

    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> 1>d:\project\c++\vs2010\asio_test\asio_test\include\asio\detail\type_traits.hpp(23): fatal error C1083: 无法打开包括文件:“boost/type_traits/add_const.hpp”: No such file or directory

my question is:

1. can I only use asio in vs2010,and not to download boost,and what is the maxium version of asio can I use?
2. If cann't,must I have to download and compile boost in my project?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have update the question,can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am sure downloaded the standalone version which named [asio-1.12.2.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/asio/files/asio/1.12.2%20%28Stable%29/)

Comment: I think with such an old compiler asio has to use boost to fill in the gaps in the standard library